# Correctly manage DLQ in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want manage a DLQ in Spring Cloud Stream using kafka.

**application.yaml**

```
server:
    port: 8091
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://IP:8761/eureka
spring:
    application:
        name: employee-consumer
    cloud:
        stream:
            kafka:
                binder:
                    brokers: IP:9092
                bindings:
                    greetings-in:
                        destination: greetings
                        contentType: application/json
                    greetings-out:
                        destination: greetings
                        contentType: application/json
            bindings:
                greetings-out:
                    consumer:
                        enableDlq: true
                        dlqName: dead-out
    kafka:
      consumer:
        group-id: A
```

As you can see in my configuration I enable dlq and set a name to the dlq topic.

To test DLQ behaviour I throw an exception on certain messages

**My listener component**

```
@StreamListener("greetings-out")
    public void handleGreetingsInput(@Payload Greetings greetings) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Greetings input -> {}", greetings);
        if (greetings.getMessage().equals("ciao")) {
            throw new Exception("eer");
        }
    }
```

In this way, the message that is equal to "ciao" throws an exception and in logs I see that  it gets processed three times

```
2018-07-09 13:19:57.256  INFO 1 --- [container-0-C-1] com.mitro.service.GreetingsListener      : Greetings input -> com.mitro.model.Greetings@3da9d701[timestamp=0,message=ciao]
2018-07-09 13:19:58.259  INFO 1 --- [container-0-C-1] com.mitro.service.GreetingsListener      : Greetings input -> com.mitro.model.Greetings@5bd62aaf[timestamp=0,message=ciao]
2018-07-09 13:20:00.262  INFO 1 --- [container-0-C-1] com.mitro.service.GreetingsListener      : Greetings input -> com.mitro.model.Greetings@c26f92b[timestamp=0,message=ciao]
2018-07-09 13:20:00.266 ERROR 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking com.mitro.service.GreetingsListener#handleGreetingsInput[1 args]; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: eer, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[32], headers={kafka_offset=3, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@510302cb, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTopic=greetings-out, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1531142397248}]
```

This is fine for me, but I don't understand why a topic called dead-out is created as result (take a  look at the image below).
[image: topics' view]

**What am I doing wrong?**

**EDIT 1: (still doesn't create topic for DLQ)**

```
server:
    port: 8091
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://IP:8761/eureka
spring:
    application:
        name: employee-consumer
    cloud:
        stream:
            kafka:
                streams:
                    binder:
                        serdeError: sendToDlq
                binder:
                    brokers: IP:9092
                    auto-create-topics: true
                bindings:
                    greetings-out:
                        destination: greetings-out
                        contentType: application/json
                        consumer:
                          enableDql: true
                          dlqName: dead-out
                          autoCommitOnError: true
                          autoCommitOffset: true
            bindings:
                greetings-out:
                    destination: greetings-out
                    contentType: application/json
                    consumer:
                        enableDlq: true
                        dlqName: dead-out
                        autoCommitOnError: true
                        autoCommitOffset: true
    kafka:
      consumer:
        group-id: A
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your properties are reversed; the common properties - destination, contentType - must be under `spring.cloud.stream.bindings`. The kafka-specific properties (enableDlq, dlqName) must be under `spring.clound.stream.kafka.bindings`.

You have them reversed.

**EDIT**

There are two problems with your (modified) config.

1. typo `enableDql` instead of `enableDlq`
2. no group - you can't have a DLQ with an anonymous consumer:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DLQ support is not available for anonymous subscriptions

This works fine:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: employee-consumer
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          auto-create-topics: true
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: dead-out
              autoCommitOnError: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
      bindings:
        input:
          group: so51247113
          destination: greetings-out
          contentType: application/json
```

and

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So51247113Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51247113Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void in(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException("fail");
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "dead-out")
    public void dlq(Message<?> in) {
        System.out.println("DLQ:" + in);
    }

}
```

Comment: I reversed the properties as you said and I got this error: 2018-07-10 10:08:05.232 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create consumer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while starting consumer:

Comment: Edited question with new yml, I tried to make it work with more properties, but still doesn't create new topic for DLQ

Comment: You still have a missing `kafka:` element for the DLQ properties. Please read my answer again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get. IDE (the image tell me I'm under spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings , where do I miss the other kafka? 
https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_consumer_properties

Comment: In your question above (edit), you have `spring: cloud: stream: bindings: greetings-out: consumer: enableDlq` it should be `spring: cloud: stream: kafka: bindings: greetings-out: consumer: enableDlq`. The destination and content type are correct.

Comment: Isn't it the binding few lines above?

Comment: Oh; I see; yes; confusing having it in both places. Let me copy your config and try it...

Comment: Ok, thank you, Off Topic: Do you think I should divide in two different yaml?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I don't know what you mean by divide here.

Comment: Two different properties file. Im'm going to try you conf, thank you

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: keep conf file cleaner, could be confusing maybe

Comment: can we move message to dlq on specific exceptions?

Comment: Don't ask new question in comments on old answers; it doesn't help people find answers to their questions. Always ask a new question instead. The simple answer is yes, but you need some code in your listener. Ask a new question with much more detail about what you are trying to do.

Comment: In @KafkaListener annotation, what is 'id' field?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in old comments. See the javadoc.